# unable to get context api values

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react js. I copied the code from "https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c".

when I am trying to read Context api values in state provider(after state is updated) those are undefined. I am able to get correct values from stateConsumer function. StateContext is global object here.

```
export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => {
  console.log(useStateValue());
  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const stateConsumer = () => {
  //console.log("SC",useContext(StateContext));
  return useContext(StateContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using examples from [this upmostly articl](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-usecontext-hook-in-react)e I think you need to modify it slightly:

```
export const StateContext = createContext([{}, () => {}]);

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useContext(StateContext);

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider=value={[value, setState]}>
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

It goes into a lot more detail about using the state and context, you should read that more to flesh out your code. It is a complex read though to be fair, but an interesting one.

Comment: Its not working.Every time in StateProvider function (after updating state also), state value is empty. My main doubt is after updating state StateProvider will be called, but in StateProvider function we are using StateContext which is already defined on module loads. But for every update stateContext is empty.